# Nginx отдача статики, wsgi

Tags: nginx, javascript

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос. Есть приложение, запускаемое при помощи nginx и wsgi, оно генерирует html-страницу где в header-ре

```
    <script src="http://localhost/js/OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>    <script src="http://localhost/map.js"></script>    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/static/css/main.css" />
```

В конфиге nginx    location / {            root            /home/user/server;            uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:3031;            #uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/app/geoserv/socket;            include         uwsgi_params;............    }

```
location ~* .+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mov) {    expires 30d;}
```

Проблема в том что страница генерируется, но при этом не подгружаются css и js. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что вам ответит сервер на http://localhost/js/OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js ?

Comment: [error] 1000#0: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/js/OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js"    failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /js/OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Comment: Вот как то так в логах. Вообще 404 Not Found

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, в примерах не было путей, а сам не сообразил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так пропишите в конфиге каталог (root dir ), где у вас лежат js файлы, для такого локейшена, вам же явно пишут что файл  /etc/nginx/html/js/OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js не найден, даю 100 гульдонов что он лежит совсем в другом месте.